# IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm using `Cursor` inside a retained `DialogFragment`. The `Cursor` is loaded by `AsyncTask` after the `DialogFragment`'s view is created and is closed when `DialogFragment` gets destroyed. Then the `Cursor` will be handed to a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Currently I'm testing on Froyo emulator. Problem is, when I scrolled fastly on the `ListView` -> dismissed the dialog -> opened it again -> the app crashed (see Log below).

I have not encountered similar problem when on my phone and there is no problem either when I wait for the `ListView` to stop scrolling before closing the dialog and opening it again.

Logcat:

```
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = my query) 
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:34)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:64)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:283)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:255)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:188)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:247)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2485)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-15 22:09:45.402: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class SearchAirportFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private Activity mContext;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor cursor = null;
    private LoadCursor taskLoad;

    public static DialogFragment newInstance(int jenisPenerbangan) {
        DialogFragment f = new SearchAirportFragment();
        f.setRetainInstance(true);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mContext = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mContext = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (taskLoad != null)
            taskLoad.cancel(false);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_airport, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_item_text, cursor, new String[] { "name" }, new int[] { R.id.text1 }, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (cursor == null && taskLoad == null) {
            taskLoad = new LoadCursor(this, 1, "test");
            taskLoad.execute();
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        adapter = null;
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        if (d != null && getRetainInstance())
            d.setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    public void updateCursor(Cursor result) {
        cursor = result;
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        }
    }


    private static class LoadCursor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {
        private String keyword;
        private WeakReference<SearchAirportFragment> fragmentReference;

        public LoadCursor(SearchAirportFragment fragment, int myflag,
            String search) {
            this.keyword = search;
            this.fragmentReference = new WeakReference<SearchAirportFragment>(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = /* my query */;
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Cursor result) {
            if (result != null) result.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            SearchAirportFragment f = fragmentReference.get();
            if (f != null && result != null) {
                f.updateCursor(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe somehow `ListView` still gets scrolled (therefore adapter's `getView()` is called) after it's destroyed.

This solves it:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
    adapter = null;
    Dialog d = getDialog();
    if (d != null && getRetainInstance())
        d.setDismissMessage(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: I bet you are closing the cursor when the dialogfragment is destroyed or paused.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA yes I close the cursor in `onDestroy()`, i have not known this problem before

Comment: Can you post your dialog fragment?

Comment: done, I added my dialogfragment. @AedonEtLIRA